# Building a bot, can't use any queries starting with /me/

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Ran into a roadblock when trying to implement people search (using names or whatever else) from an app-only authenticated bot. Is there a way for the bot to query the graph without it having an identity? I can do this:

```
 GET "https://microsoft.graph.com/beta/users/" + userPrincipalName + "@hooli.com"
```

But I can't do this:

```
GET "https://microsoft.graph.com/beta/me/people/?$search=" + "\"" + query + "\""
```

It makes sense, the bot isn't a user object. I just wanted to see if you had any suggestions for this scenario. (The idea is for this bot to be published to SharePoint, and eventually to SfB when that becomes a real option.)

Answer (score 0):

Very cool that you are connecting to Microsoft Graph with a bot scenario! Couple of things here.  Firstly the /me construct **requires** that a user is signed in, as /me is an alias for the currently signed-in user.  App-only will not work with this request, as you have discovered.  You've also discovered that you can do a more rudimentary search only through the users entity.  You can do something a bit smarter here by using a startswith search together with an "or" conjunctive clause (see below).  However $search is not currently supported for the users entity.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'xxx') or startswith(mail, 'xxx') or startswith(userPrincipalName, 'xxx')
```

Secondly the people entity is a search that is done from the point of view of the signed-in user.  It can't currently be done by app-only (people is only supported under me).  Will need to get others to provide some info on whether a generic people search will be supported through this API. Also people is still in preview.

Please let us know if the suggested workaround (using startswith) is adequate for now, and can be replaced later once there is a more powerful $search support.

One other thing - if the user is interacting with the bot (say through a web site or a mobile client) - could the user be signed in already, and the bot use the [on behalf of flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) to call into MS Graph from your bot as the user?
Hope this helps,